# Angular - *ngFor and MEAN App

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a mean app running succesfully and I am at the stage of adding UIkit to style the application. Having some trouble with the ngFor and rendering the correct elements on the page.

So here is the code for the layout sans backend code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Automation | Adam Sackfield</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar uk-sticky>
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">
      <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="34" viewBox="0 0 28 34" class="uk-margin-small-right uk-svg" ratio="1">
          <polygon fill="#fff" points="19.1,4.1 13.75,1 8.17,4.45 13.6,7.44 "></polygon>
          <path fill="#fff" d="M21.67,5.43l-5.53,3.34l6.26,3.63v9.52l-8.44,4.76L5.6,21.93v-7.38L0,11.7v13.51l13.75,8.08L28,25.21V9.07 L21.67,5.43z"></path>
        </svg> Home Automation
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-navbar-right">
      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
          <li class="uk-active"><a href="index.html">Control Centre</a></li>
          <li class="uk-parent"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="uk-container">
    <h1 class="uk-h1 uk-text-center">Control Centre</h1>
    <ul class="uk-tab uk-margin-auto" uk-switcher>
      <li><a href="#">Sensors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="uk-switcher animation: uk-animation-fade">
      <li>
        <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
        <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
          <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
              <h2 class="uk-h2">Lounge Light</h2>
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">On</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="!device.onStatus" -->
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default switchOff" disabled>Off</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="device.onStatus" -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
              <h2 class="uk-h2">Kitchen Light</h2>
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" disabled>On</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="!device.onStatus" -->
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default switchOff">Off</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="device.onStatus" -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
              <h2 class="uk-h2">Bedroom Light</h2>
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">On</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="!device.onStatus" -->
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default switchOff" disabled>Off</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="device.onStatus" -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li>Hello again!</li>
        <li>Bazinga!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the Mean app with the *ngFor

```
<div class="uk-container">
  <h1 class="uk-h1 uk-text-center">Control Centre</h1>
  <ul class="uk-tab uk-margin-auto" uk-switcher>
    <li><a href="#">Sensors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="uk-switcher animation: uk-animation-fade">
    <li>
      <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
      <div *ngFor="let device of devices" class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div>
      <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
        <h2 class="uk-h2">{{ device.name }}</h2>
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">On</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="!device.onStatus" -->
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-default switchOff" disabled>Off</button> <!-- In final app add: ng-disabled="device.onStatus" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li>Hello again!</li>
  <li>Bazinga!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Screenshot of rendered views [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh4MP.jpg)

Notice inside the views the class "uk-first-column" is added on each iteration (although not sure if this is the problem). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. As you can see from the screenshots on the ngFor each device is full width whereas on the simple UIkit version they are split in to 3 columns.

Comment: Move the `*ngFor="let device of devices"` to the inner first `<div>` just before the `uk-card`. This will prevent repeating the entire container `uk-grid`, and only performs the repeat on the the children. Let us know.

Comment: @Searching - Thanks for the tip. Yes that did work. So simple, I was under the impression that ngFor looped everything inside of the tag excluding the one calling the ngFor. So I guess it includes the tag that calls it too. Thanks again, if you want to add this as an answer I will mark as solved.

Comment: No probs. Happy coding!